# IOS/Xcode: storyboard screen turning black

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am just learning Xcode.  I did something that caused a view controller to turn black below the navigation bar when you build app.

It looks white in storyboard.

Also, when I pull a label onto the storyboard, it aligns to the left margin and does not show the drag boxes around it.

I may have inadvertently clicked something but when I compared it in attributes and identity inspectors line by line to another project, nothing seems amiss, i.e. everything is the default value.

Has anyone run across this?

There is not code in associated class that would cause this as it is generic i.e. plain vanilla.

Would appreciate any suggestions.  Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that little information i'd say you removed the root view of the controller?

Either way, you say there is no code, so I'd suggest you simply delete that controller and create another one (bottom right, objects, viewcontroller). Since it's empty you're not gonna lose any data or time :)

Then link it to your class in the Identity Inspector and you're good to go as if it was a new one.

Comment: I deleted and recreated it.  However, I am noticing a lot of spooky things happen in Xcode and it is already getting old rebuilding the program to solve these strange things in rendering...